# updating n elements in $O(\lg{n})$ time

Tags: data-structures, red-black-trees

I need to devise a data structure $S$ with the following functions:

- BUILD($S$) - build the data structure from a series of $n$ elements in time $O(n \lg{n})$
- INSERT($S$, $k$) - insert a new element with the key $k$ to $S$ in time $O(\lg{n})$
- DELETE($S$, $p$) - delete the element $p$ from $S$ in time $O(\lg{n})$
- D-SUCCESSOR($S$, $p$, $d$) - return the $d$-successor of $p$ in time $O(\lg{n})$ where $d$-successor of $p$ is the $d$-th element after $p$ if the elements where ordered by their key
- DECREASE-UPTO($S$, $k$, $val$) - decrease by $val$ all keys in $S$ where the key is not larger than $k$, in $O(\lg{n})$ time

---

I've managed to do the first 4 points using order static tree, as an extension of red black tree, but I'm having trouble with the last one, assuming $k$ is bigger than all elements in $S$ the function will need to update the values of all $n$ elements in $S$ how can this be done in $O(\lg{n})$ time?

Comment: "in $O(lg{n})$" means the time complexity of the function needs to be $O(lg{n})$. $N$ and $n$ both mean the number of elements in $S$

Comment: I'd _start_ with (5). Since there are up to n values to change, this can happen in O(log n) only if you design a data structure so you can make a small (log n) modification to your data that can affect n values. So your data must be stored in some distributed way.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to maintain a balanced BST where each node is suitably augmented with satellite information, as you have already done for the first 4 points.

To handle the last point you just need to add a new field $\delta(v)$ to each node $v$. The meaning of this field is as follows:

If $u$ is a vertex of the tree, the key **stored** in $u$ is $k(u)$, and $\langle r = u_1, u_2, \dots, u_\ell = u \rangle$  is the path from the root $r$ of the tree to $u$ then the key $k^*(u)$ that is **logically represented** by $u$ is:
$$
k^*(u) = k(u) + \sum_{i=1}^\ell \delta(u_i).
$$

This fields can be maintained while the other operations are performed, while preserving the BST order of the represented keys in the tree. I.e., if $v$ is the left (reps. right) child of $u$ then $k^*(v) < k^*(u)$ (resp. $k^*(v) > k^*(u)$).

Comment: how does this allow me to update all keys smaller or equal a given $k$ by a given value? All I can see is that now I have a field that sum the total route from the root to a given node. If I have a tree with 2 at its root, 1 the left son and 3 the right and I call DECREASE-UPTO with $k=3$ and $val=1$ I now have a tree with 1 as root 0 is left son and 2 is right son, but I don't see how does your answer give me this result

Comment: Let $v$ be a vertex of your BST and let $T_v$ be the subtree rooted at $v$. To decrease by $x$ the value of all the keys stored in $T_v$ you only have to decrement $\delta(v)$ by $x$, which requires $O(1)$ time. Moreover, given any value $k$, you can find a collection of $O(\log n)$ vertex-disjoint subtrees  or single vertices of your BST that contain all keys that are not larger than $k$. This can be done in $O(\log n)$ time. Once this is done, you only need to update $O(\log n)$ keys and fields $\delta(\cdot)$ which, by the above discussion, takes $O(\log n)$ overall time.

Comment: In your specific example, if $r$ is the root vertex, you only need to decrease $\delta(r)$ by $1$.